CloudCompare Mesh OBJ not saving coordinate system
I have a LAS file which I have meshed in CloudCompare
I've output as an obj, and tried to upload into Cesium Ion - however, it's not appearing in the correct location?
I assured I kept the position when importing the las file etc, and the coordinates for the bounding box on cloud compare are correct. So why isn't Cesium placing it correctly?
